# Django 2.1 startproject throws weird error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to start my first app in Django 2.1 on Python 3.4. It's the first time with this versions, previously I worked only with Django 1.10 and Python 2.7. Everything on Ubunutu 14.04

I created a virtualenv, mostly following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04

However with slight changes of my own because first a locale issue appeared and was fixed like this:

```
sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Afterwards I changed the aliases like this:

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

That's all. After installing django==2.1 and runing:

```
django-admin.py start project myproject
```

This error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from django.conf import settings
    File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
    File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/skw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 12
        return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
                            ^
```

Inside this file functional.py in django my lint is showing a syntax error exactly at the line 12 ... but not sure if that's relevant, since I didn't change the syntax to python3 yet.

Because of this I can not start a new project, how to solve this?

EDIT:
It seems like it would run in Python2 not 3. However when I tried this:

```
python3 path/bin/django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

The result was exactly the same. I also did this with python3.4, still the same. Meanwhile it's been couple of hours and around 6 workspaces created and deleted. This probably is something basic that I am too tired to see but what?

```
python -V
Python 3.4.3

python3 -V 
Python 3.4.3

python3.4 -V
Python 3.4.3
```

When looking into python-v, django import work no problem.

Comment: Looks to me you run this in Python-2. The fact that you define an alias probably does not work if you use `django-admin.py`. Try using `python3 django-admin.py startproject myproject`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Came in to my mind as well. Tried but forgot to mention. It's exactly the same, no difference at all. Same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django 2.1 is not supported on Python 3.4 - only 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7.

Release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/

Comment: I knew it was something stooopid .. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The python version you use is `3.4.3`. But `django==2.1` will install Django 2.1.

> Django 2.1 supports Python 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7. Django 2.0 is the last version to support Python 3.4. We **highly recommend** and only officially support the latest release of each series.

**Source** [Django 2.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/)

So, You need to install to resolve it

> pip3 install Django==2.0.0